# ¿Cómo hago para enviar un código nuevo a otra rama?

Tags: git, git-push, git-commit

Al inicio tenía 2 ramas: master y branch2.

todo el tiempo estuve trabajando sobre ***branch2*** y cuando terminé mi tarea e iba a pushear mi código, el desarrollador me dijo que debía enviar mi código a una rama que era **branch10**.

Entonces hice las instrucciones básicas que me sé.

1. `git fetch origin branch10`
2. `git status` (vi las clases que modifiqué)
3. `git add` (agregué las clases)
4. `git commit` (y agregué un nombre a mi commit para enviar)
5. `git push origin branch2`

Cuando revisé mi Pull request me di cuenta que se subieron otros cambios. No entiendo por qué.

Entonces, ¿cómo hago para que Branch10 tenga el codigo que trabajé? Únicamente lo que yo hice.

Answer (score 4):

> [Respuesta Original](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13897766/8933039)

Al pasar a una rama no predeterminada, debe especificar la referencia de origen y la referencia de destino:

```
git push origin branch1:branch2
```

O

```
git push <remote> <rama con nuevos cambios>:<rama a la que estás presionando>
```

> Informaciones útiles (Traducir del inglés):
>
> - [¿Cómo fusionar mis cambios locales no confirmados en otra rama de Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/556986/8933039)
> - [Mueva el trabajo existente y no comprometido a una nueva branch en Git](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1394804/8933039)
> - [Mueva los commit(s) más recientes a una nueva rama con Git](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1628584/8933039)

Answer (score 2):

si has seguido los pasos que indicas:

1. **git fetch origin branch10:** sincronizas la rama branch10 en tu local, con la que hay en servidor.
2. **git status** (vi las clases que modifiqué)
3. **git add** (agregué las clases)
4. **git commit** (y agregué un nombre a mi commit para enviar)
5. **git push origin branch2**: subes los cambios en la rama Branch2.

de momento la cosa es correcta: tu rama branch2 esta actualizada a lo ultimo que debe tener... PERO no incluye lo de branch10.

Si en este momento has mirado el contenido de branch10, puede ser que tengas algo nuevo en el servidor,

si lo que quieres es que Branch10 tenga tus ultimos cambios, lo que debes hacer ahora es:

1. cambiarte a la rama branch10.
2. git pull origin/branch10 (para sincronizar los cambios que tenga en remoto)
3. git merge branch2 (incluyes los ultimos cambios de tu branch2 en branch10)
4. git commit
5. git push origin branch10

Comment: Si, lo que yo quiero es que Branch10 tenga mi codigo que trabajé

Comment: revisa la solucion que te he pasado, la he actualizado para corregir el paso 1, que es cambiar a la rama local de branch10